# How to expand this polynomial division?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, learning

My Physics teacher gave me a problem and its solution, what I have todo is to expand the solution, but when I do it I do not get to the same solution he says is the right one, here is the problem:

> We cut off a rectangle **ABCD** along the line **DE** through the corner **D**, so when we suspend the plate **ABED** from the point **E** the line **DA**, is on horizontal position. Calculate the magnitude **EB**

[image: The problem and its solutions]

The image below is the solution, What I am not able to figure out is how the teacher solved the  polynomial division and get to that result.

[image: Solution]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try multiplying each term in the numerator and denominator by $6/h$, then simplifying the denominator.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Another question, how did you know that?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig How, did you get to that? please answer

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do polynomial division

[image: prog solution]

Comment: Yeah, I know, But I have to put all the process from ah(h/2) till 3a^2 - (a-x)^2.

Comment: Oh, ok; I thought you were just having trouble with getting his final answer.  So for that step you can just factor an h out of both terms in the numerator and both in the denominator, so h/h will cancel, then multiply top and bottom by 2 and by 3 (or 6) to get rid of the fractions.